# Why individual odds ratio are insignificant, but the meta-analysis results give significant estimation?

Tags: statistical-significance, meta-analysis

I have a group of covariates and individually they are balanced between treatment group and control group.

It's well established that even if the covariates from the treatment group and control group are individually statistically balanced, they might be jointly imbalanced. (i.e. if I calculate $$T_n = Z_1^2+Z_2^2+...+Z_n^2$$, and find the corresponding p-value of $T_n$ on the chi-square distribution with n-degree of freedom.

Suppose I calculate the odds of the covariates in the treatment group and control group and pool them together using a meta-analysis fashion. In that case, it seems the conclusion is still valid. The result can be seen from the table, all the covariates have individually insignificant odds ratio, but when I pool them together, the overall odds ratio become significant.

I have a problem understanding why this is the case. I can understand it when we are performing joint chi-square test because we are summing up individual chi-square results and each time when we add another chi-square score to the equation, the degree of freedom of the chi-square distribution changes, hence the shape of the distribution changes. It could be that the rate of change in $T$ and the rate of change in the probability are different which resulted in the disparity in the conclusion.

But what about meta-analysis? I think meta-analysis at a high level is basically weighted average of individual OR, and the weighting is usually inversely related to the standard deviation of the factor that's being weighted. If it's only a weighted average, why would the consolidated OR become significant? Can some one explain it in a high level intuitively and if possible demonstrate this result mathematically?

[image]

Comment: The phenomenon you describe is at one level the whole point of meta-analysis. The overall estimate is estimated more precisely. Look at your first sub-panel where the CI is narrower for the summary than for ether of the two primary studies.